# Substract a cell (if it has a # value) with rows below it in a different column if the conditions are the same

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using this equation  =IF(K2=0,0, K2-I2) to show the difference in a cell with what a client has to pay vs what he has paid (negative if he paid less than what he had to and positive if he paid more). How would I modify this equation to substract from the next amount paid (k3 in this case) or the following (k4) if they didn't pay in k3 so the difference becomes 0 if its used with the added condition that the name at Column C matches.

[image]

The first column is the amount someone needs to pay, the second is what they paid, the fourth shows the difference and the fifth states what it is. I would like the difference from the first row to use the paid amount from the second row to substract from it before applying itself to the difference in the second row. Is this possible? I've tried looking for hours in google with no luck.

Edit:

[image]

This is how I would like it to look (this is manually inputting the data). The amount the client has to pay each month is 425.65 so the second month he pays 400 it would first cancel the first 'debt' to then count towards his second month payment which results in more debt than the first pay cycle.

Comment: Could you include column / row headings in your screenshot so that there's less addition/subtraction required on this side pls? :)

Answer (score 1):

**Prelim**

Worksheet [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j962b70igT5YlXSiag?e=jn9xPe) / screenshot below refer.

If you don't mind using a 'helper' column (I don't see any other way around this, unless you go down the 'VBA/Pivot' route, given the nature of the sum function re arrays) - then this should (I think!:) address the issue...

**Eqns**

*Helper*

```
=IF(OR(B3<>B4,SUM(D$3:D3*(B$3:B3=B3))>=INDEX($C$3:$C$11,MATCH(B3,$B$3:$B$11,0))),1,0)
```

This turns 1 when the sum of "Paid" is at least >= "Owing" for the same individual.  Assumes: rows ordered chronologically, grouped by 'Person' attribute.

*Net ultimate*

```
=IF(B3=B2,"",SUM(D3:INDEX($D$3:$D$11,MATCH(B3&1,$B$3:$B$11&$E$3:$E$11,0))))
```

**Screenshots**

[image: Helper]

[image: Sum until net liab >= 0]

This sums from the first instance of 'Paid' for a given Person, to the Paid value corresponding to the first instance of a '1' in the Helper column.

**Examples**

- In this case, A owes £1k at outset, pays £450 initially, then pays a further £700 (i.e. has *overpaid* by £150).  As such, the 'Net ultimate' figure reports back £1,150 (=£450 + £700); it doesn't consider the £50 (did you want it to? If so the function becomes a lot easier, and reduces to a regular sumifs...).
- For B: net ultimate = £1,025 (the total amounts paid never exceed what is owing, so tally all amounts paid by B)
- Same goes for £1k and C....